# Windows Phone 8 Multiple View Models Not Working

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have multiple view models on Windows Phone 8, this works on Windows Phone 7, but not 8.

In my MainPage.xaml code:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="musicList">
    <phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Genre}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
       <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
       </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Song}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

In my MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
musicList.ItemsSource = App.Music;
```

In my App.xaml.cs code:

```
using MyMusic.Assets.ViewModels.Music;

private static MusicList m_Music = new MusicList();

public static MusicList Music
{
    get { return m_Music; }
}
```

In my /Assets/ViewModels/Music/MusicList.cs

```
public class MusicList : ObservableCollection<Genre>
{
    public MusicList()
       {
        this.Clear();
       }
}
```

In my /Assets/ViewModels/Music/Genre.cs

```
public class Genre : ObservableCollection<Artist>
{
    public Genre()
    {
        this.Clear();
    }

    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

In my /Assets/ViewModels/Music/Artist.cs

```
public class Artist : ObservableCollection<SongItem>
{
    public Artist()
    {
        this.Clear();
    }

    public string Artist { get; set; }
}
```

In my /Assets/ViewModels/Music/SongItem.cs

```
public class SongItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Song { get; set; }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string thePropertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(thePropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This code in the MainPage.xaml code reaches "Genre" and then it doesn't get any of the other fields after that on Windows Phone 8, however, on Windows Phone 7, it would keep going through all the modules.

How do I get this to get all the module fields that have been added?

It keeps reporting an error when debugging:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Artist' property not found on 'Assets.ViewModels.MusicList.Genre' 'Assets.ViewModels.Music.Genre' (HashCode=21418771). BindingExpression: Path='Artist' DataItem='Assets.ViewModels.Music.Genre' (HashCode=21418771); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

I have this linked with `ObservableCollection<>` and it's not linking it to get the "Artist" string as the error states. What would be causing this? How do I change the path to Music.Genre.Artist, so that it will work?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method at the setters?

Comment: On a side note: you don't need the `Clear()` methods inside the constructors since they are empty on creation.

Comment: Thanks for the side notes, any idea on why it's not working correctly though?

Comment: I cant see it from your code but usually that error is when you have a problem with the datacontext, or something like one item is not public where another is. But for your case it looks like something like datacontext.

Comment: Is this an exact duplication of your LongListSelector's XAML? If the list's `IsGroupingEnabled` property isn't set to true, you could expect behavior exactly like this.

Comment: Ithibodeaux --- THANK YOU! Why did they even put that option in WP8? It's a horrible option (in my opinion). However, when I set the IsGroupingEnabled="True" it did provide me the "Artist", however, I still cannot see the Song's per Artist group. Would there be a way to fix this? I think it might deal with ListFooterTemplate.